# how to use tanf from c++ in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to use tanf but i cant find code in js that this does
tanf is used in c and c++ converted the code from c++ to js
i try to make a 3d view without opengl or other librarys
just for fun :P

sorry for bad english :$
my code

```
var Vector3 = function(X, Y, Z) {
this.X = X;
this.Y = Y;
this.Z = Z;
```

};

```
var Matrix = {
    CreateProjection: function(fov, aspect, near, far) {
        var bottom = -near * Math.tanf(0.5 * fov * Math.PI / 180.0);
        var top = -bottom;
        var left = aspect * bottom;
        var right = -left;
        return Matrix.CreateFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    },
    CreateFrustum: function(left, right, bottom, top, near, far) {
        var dx = right - left;
        var dy = bottom - top;
        var dz = far - near;

        var mx = 0.5 * (left + right);
        var my = 0.5 * (bottom + top);
        var mz = 0.5 * (near + far);

        var n = near;
        var nf = near * far;

        var matrix = [2.0 * n / dx, 0.0, 2.0 * mx / dx, 0.0,
                      0.0, 2.0 * n / dy, 2.0 * my / dy, 0.0,
                      0.0, 0.0, -2.0 * mz / dz, -2.0 * nf / dz,
                      0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0
                      ];
        return matrix;
    },
    Translate: function(vector) {
        var matrix = [
            1, 0, 0, vector.X,
            0, 1, 0, vector.Y,
            0, 0, 1, vector.Z,
            0, 0, 0, 1
        ];
        return matrix;

    },
    MatrixToVector: function(matrix) {
        var vectornew = [0, 0, 0, 0];
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            //next row
            for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                if (matrix[(i * 4) + c] != 0) {
                    vectornew[i] += matrix[(i * 4) + c];
                }
            }
        }
        return new Vector3(vectornew[0], vectornew[1], vectornew[3]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Use Math.tan instead of tanf.

Comment: If you've got access to a c++ compiler, you could test that quite easily :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `tanf` in JavaScript, as all numbers are doubles anyway. Use [`Math.tan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/tan) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Math.tan` function.